# pgfplots: How can I remove the markers when using addplot3?

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to remove the circles that are the markers in an `addplot3` parametrized helix.  How can this be done?

I have tried `markers = none` and `markers = false`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    samples = 100,
    domain = 0:5 * pi,
    samples y = 0,
    view = {60}{30},
    ]
    \addplot3 ({cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))}, {5 * x});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's `no markers`.

Comment: @percusse are you making an answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: No problem, you can answer it your own if you like. Or we can close it or delete it. But maybe someone else stumble on it no matter how small the info?

Comment: @percusse I think you should make the answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three equivalent approaches which I'd like to discuss as this question appears to arise now and then:

1 using `mark=none` as add-on option. In the absence of style options, your `\addplot3` command uses the `cycle list` to determine the plot style (and ended up with blue and these markers). You can add `\addplot3+[mark=none]` to *add* the option `mark=none` to that list:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    samples = 100,
    domain = 0:5 * pi,
    samples y = 0,
    view = {60}{30},
    ]
    \addplot3+[mark=none] ({cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))}, {5 * x});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

2 you can provide your own, self-contained and complete option list by means of `\addplot3[blue]`. Since this does not explicitly request a mark, there won't be any:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    samples = 100,
    domain = 0:5 * pi,
    samples y = 0,
    view = {60}{30},
    ]
    \addplot3[blue] ({cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))}, {5 * x});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

3 You can write `no markers` into your axis. This key comes is applied to every plot inside of the axis; it overrules any specification of the `cycle list`. In other words: it allows you to use the automatically determined plot styles, but it overrules marker specifications found in any plot style. This option is global in its character whereas the other two are local:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    no markers,
    samples = 100,
    domain = 0:5 * pi,
    samples y = 0,
    view = {60}{30},
    ]
    \addplot3 ({cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))}, {5 * x});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The outcome is always the same, namely

[image]